# FULL text search in mysql for filering process

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

my table name is contact and its fields are (id, domainname, companyname, customername).

In contact table we are using urlencode() to save the domainname through php.

In my filter using full text search for domainname, companyname and customername. compamyname and customer name working fine in full text search.but domain name is not working for reason urlencode().

please suggest how can i resolve this issue.

Comment: Why do you need to use `urlencode()` to save the domain name? Do the domains have spaces/special characters in them?

Comment: some times the domain name have some special characters. so that reason only we can use urlencode().

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/14800891/1957346