# MySQL Select with URL (strange characters in database)

Tags: mysql, url

I want to do a "select all" from a table, using an URL. However the URLs stored in my database have funny characters; an URL in my database looks something like this:

> http%3A%2F%2Fwww.indeed.co.uk%2Fviewjob%3Fjk%3D62643ba09fe2e936%26qd%3DUl8d87NuQZQD4fDpyxUj6Q3nWG6Z80ksB5Olwd1QWW3wG-YZeyT0yxf8fUYia7g-jLgw8Q9quijZp6li7FQTOh_bZiy_HhLQe1iSKacCzeM%26indpubnum%3D2878078796677777%26atk%3D185867g360mq25sg

How would I select this by using a normal URL string such as "http://www.indeed.co.uk/blablabla", without all the funny %3A%2F characters.

Or is there a way to insert the urls into the database without these characters getting added in. If so how?

Comment: Google 'URL encoding', those characters are not funny, but useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use PHP, you can use the function `urlencode` :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE url = '" . urlencode($urlToSearch) . "'";
```

[Documentation PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.urlencode.php)

Answer (score 0):

Those are [URI encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) characters. It's not clear how those ended up in your database, though it's possible they weren't properly decoded before being saved.

It's sort of possible to [decode these in MySQL alone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993754/mysql-select-with-url-decode) but it's usually better to use a scripting language of some sort to do the conversion for you.