# How to get value based on key in MySQL if that value is URL encoded

Tags: mysql

My sample Data:

```
%7B%22message%22%3A%22hi%22%2C%22message_type%22%3A%22text%22%2C%22nickName%22%3A%22Srinivasanvasan%20Prakasam%22%2C%22utcTimestamp%22%3A1652999988927%7D
```

i used `JSON_EXTRACT` function but i am getting

> Invalid JSON error

Comment: That's not JSON, why do you think you can use `JSON_EXTRACT()`?

Comment: Apparently that's url-encoded JSON. MySQL doesn't have a URL decode function, so you'll need to extract what you want in another programming language.

Comment: Or you could fix the way you store the data by not using URL encoding.

Comment: You'll need to URL-decode it first, which can be done using this ugly function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993754/mysql-select-with-url-decode. Or you could do what @Barmar suggested and use another programming language to do the unescaping.

Comment: @Julia, Yes i tried those functions that you mentioned. But, if its is large data it takes some time to process. I need only messge_type value

Answer (score 0):

I think you first need to decode the url and then upload to database in order to do JSON_EXTRACT.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried those functions that you mentioned. But, if its is large data it takes some time to process. So that only  I asked particular value

Comment: Best way to speed up the process of fetching data is by creating different columns or tables as per the requirement. Hope it helps.